# Install offline Bootstrap in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I don't have any way to have internet on my pc and I want to install Bootstrap in my Angular project by downloading it and calling it in my `index.html` so i can use it offline. Can't use `npm i` or anything related to internet besides downloading the Bootstrap zip

I just put its folder in "src" and called it with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src\bootstrap\css\bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="src\bootstrap\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This isn't working, should I download also popper.js and Jquery? Or should I change something in `Angular.json`?

Comment: Put your files in the `assets` folder and request them from there.

Comment: Also, it's / for file paths, not \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the files in the assets folders. It's better to import those files in `angular.json` instead of `index.html`. You will also have to include JQuery and popper as in official bootstrap documentation:

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
>   Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript
>   plugins.

```
"styles": [
  "src/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css""
],
"scripts": [
  "src/assets/jquery/remainingpath...",
  "src/assets/popper/remainingpath...",
  "src/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using assets folder for static files.So move your files to assets and change links like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\bootstrap\css\bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="assets\bootstrap\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also you will need to add jquery as well

Answer (score 0):

instal the bootstrap in your angular project through the terminal

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Import boostrap via Angular.Json file

```
  "styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

run the command in the terminal

```
npm i @popperjs/core
```

Start the serve

```
ng serve
```